# sjPlot plot_model distance between lines

Tags: sjplot

I did this plot with the sjPlot Package and the following command:

```
plot_model(fit, type = "pred", terms = c("degree_of_urbanization", "language"), dot.size = 2) + labs(y = "NEFI Overall Score", x = "Degree of urbanization", title = "Predicted values of NEFI Overall Score")
```

How can I change the distance between those lines. They are much too close and I don't want to make my plot much wider.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use something like dodge = .5. sjPlot simply wraps ggeffects for marginal effects plots. Some arguments from plot_model() are passed down to ggeffects plot() method. See https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/reference/plot.html